# Conditional probability. How to calculate this?

Tags: probability

We are rolling a dice twice. What is the probability that in second throw we get `5` knowing that sum of eyelets was even?

We have:
 $\Omega = 6 * 6 = 36$.
$A = \{5\}$ - event of getting 5 at the second roll
$B = \{1,3\}$ - desired results in first roll in order to get even sum
$A∩B = \{\{1,5\},\{3,5\}\}$
$P(A∩B) = \frac{2}{36}$
$P(B) = \frac{2}{6}$
$P(A|B) = \frac{2}{36} * \frac{6}{2} = \frac{1}{6}$

This is how I tried to do that, but is it correct?

**Edit**:

I assumed we wanted 5 only in second roll, but that misses one even sum possibility. So, now $B=\{1,3,5\}$ and $A∩B = \{\{1,5\},\{3,5\},\{5,5\}\}$  but still $P(A|B) = \frac{3}{36} * \frac{6}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$

Comment: What about a 5 on the first roll?

Comment: I assumed that we want 5 only as second result.

Comment: But then you clearly miss one possibility where the sum was even.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I will add note.

Comment: Your setup is not okay. E.g. there is no difference between "throwing $3$ as first and $5$ as second" and  "throwing $5$ as first and $3$ as second". This because $\{3,5\}=\{5,3\}$.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by simply counting all the possibilities.

So lets see when the sum of the rolls can be even. Let $X_1$ be the number on roll $1$ and $X_2$ be the event on roll $2$. We can have the following combinations of $(X_1,X_2)$ such that $X_1+X_2$ is even:

$$(1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(2,2),(2,4),(2,6),(3,1),(3,3),(3,5),(4,2),(4,4),(4,6),(5,1),(5,3),(5,5),(6,2),(6,4),(6,6)$$

These represent the only ways to get an even sum after 2 rolls. Clearly there are 18 ways to achieve this. Now lets see which of the above options has $X_2=5$. There is $(1,5)$,$(3,5)$ and $(5,5)$, i.e. 3 ways.

So the probability that we get a $5$ on the $2^{nd}$ roll, given the sum of the rolls is even, is the number of ways that we have a 5 on the second roll AND the sum is even (3 ways) divided by the number of ways $X_1+X_2$ is even (18 ways).

So let us define the event $A$ that the second roll is a $5$ and the event $B$ that $X_1+X_2$ is even, i.e. the sum of the 2 rolls is even. Then the desired probability is:
$$P(A|B)=\frac {P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac {P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac {\frac 12 \frac 16}{\frac 12}=\frac {\frac 1{12}}{\frac 12}=\frac 16$$

This is exactly your answer, with the only difference being that I have defined my events differently.

Please let me know if I can clarify!

Answer (score 1):

You are going for $\Omega=36$ probably meaning that it has $36$ elements and actually should be something like $|\Omega|=36$.

Then if you want to do it *properly* you should say:

- $\Omega=\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$
- $A=\{(x,5)\mid y\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$
- $B=\{(x,y)\mid x,y\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\wedge x+y\text{ is even}\}$

Then $A\cap B=\{(1,5),(3,5),(5,5)\}$.

All outcomes have the same probability and there are $36$ so $P(\{x,y\})=\frac1{36}$ for every $(x,y)\in\Omega$, leading to $P(A\cap B)=\frac3{36}$ and $P(B)=\frac{18}{36}$ so that:$$P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)=\frac3{36}/\frac{18}{36}=\frac16$$

Answer (score -1):

You are most definitely right (although you are missing the possibility of the first throw being 5). This tells you that the events "the sum of the dice is even" and "the second throw was 5" are **independent**.

If you want, you can check the results in a simulation; for instance, the following julia code gives you the answer you are looking for

```
julia> throws = rand(1:6,100000,2);
julia> secondthrow = throws[find(iseven.(sum(throws,2))),2];
julia> mean(secondthrow.==5)
0.1662898417335281
```

which is close to your result of 1/6 :)

Comment: Another example that my intuition plays tricks to me... thanks a lot!